# Characters appearing naturally in arithmetic functions

Tags: number-theory, characters, arithmetic-functions

Let $r_2(n)$ denote the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of 2 squares. It is well-known that 
$$r_2(n) = 4\sum_{d \mid n} \chi(d),$$
where $\chi$ is the non-principal character modulo $4$.

My question is: Are there other examples of characters appearing in a naturally occurring arithmetic function?

And what really interests me - Does it ever happen that a non-real character appears?

Comment: There are other examples coming from other quadratic forms; e.g. the number of representations of $n$ of the form $x^2 + xy + y^2$ should involve the non-principal character $\bmod 3$. More generally look up Dedekind zeta functions and Hecke characters.